# How to move a second div at the same rate as first div jquery UI dragged?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

If I have 2 `<divs>`, a and b that are separate divs that are absolute positioned. If I drag DIV B,  can move anywhere. If I drag A, then DIV B will move by the same offset as that moved by div A.

What I know so far is this, however, despite being able to place div B anywhere I want. Upon moving div A, div B just snaps back to the place next to div A..

```
$('.a, .b').draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        $('.a').css({
            top: ui.offset.top + 'px',
            left: ui.offset.left + 100 + 'px'
        });
    }
});
```

Is there a way I can add some kind of "mouseoffset" to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.a, .b').draggable({
        start: function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('b')){
                var p = $(this).position();
                $(this).data('lastLeft',p.left);
                $(this).data('lastTop',p.top);
            }
        },
        stop: function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('b')){
                $(this).removeData('lastLeft');
                $(this).removeData('lastTop');
            }
        },
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            if($(this).hasClass('b')){
                var p = $(this).position();
                $(this).data('lastLeft',p.left);
                $(this).data('lastTop',p.top);

                var dx = ui.position.left - $(this).data('lastLeft');
                var dy = ui.position.top - $(this).data('lastTop');
                $('.a').each(function(){
                    var p = $(this).position();
                    $(this).css({
                        left: (p.left + dx) + "px",
                        top: (p.top + dy) + "px"
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Working jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dkJFh/1/

It basically saves the start position of B on every mousemove so it can calculate the offset next time.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this. This may solve your problem I think:

```
$('#div1').draggable({
        drag: function(event, ui) {
        $('#div2').css({
            top: ui.offset.top + 'px',
            left: ui.offset.left + 100 + 'px'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice try, but not quite. Notice when you move div1 after you moved div2 somewhere, div2 snaps back to its original place attached to div1... the true solution would have div2 stay where its at whereever it is moved, but when moving div1, div2 would move the same offset that div1 moved. It is a start though.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired effect by thinking about the problem slightly differently. Nesting B within A will let you do this easily (the IE workaround notwithstanding):

**HTML:**

```
<div class='a' style="position:relative;">
  <p>div A</p>
  <div class='b' style="position:absolute;">div B</div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$('.a, .b').draggable({
});
// IE sucks, so must prevent bubbling on inner div else both divs
//    become draggable with strange results
$('.b').mousedown(function(e) {
    if($.browser.msie) {
         e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```